# RTF support of UIWebView/QLPreviewController or iOS in general

Tags: ios, uiwebview, rtf, nsattributedstring, qlpreviewcontroller

The [Technical Q&A QA1630](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1630/_index.html) says that an `UIWebView` supports RTF-docments. Also the [`QLPreviewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/networkinginternet/reference/QLPreviewController_Class/index.html) should support RTF. Now I tried that and found the following out:

- Footers/Headers are not supported at all
- Positioning is different than e.g. in Word
- Text font & size looks different than e.g. in Word
- formatting marks are not hidden
- images are not displayed

Also I noted that TextEdit on Mac also doesn't support this. Some of the points I can overcome, but I need the footers, headers and images. How would I get support for this or I'm doing something wrong? Are there alternative approaches?

I tried to use `loadRequest` (directly stored as file) instead of `loadData` (only in a variable). There is no difference. Also I tried the `QLPreviewController` with the same result. I also tried `NSAttributedString` as [Apple stated](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-8.0/)

> Show RTF files to the user is to use the Quick Look framework
>   (QLPreviewController) or to load an NSAttributedString from the RTF
>   file and show it in an UITextView, which will render the content in a
>   much cleaner way.

Here the plain text content of the rtf file was shown as expected.

How can I properly display a RTF-file with headers, footers and images?